# Struct in Class brings up error when class is used in array

Tags: c++, arrays, struct

When trying to create an array of my class, I was getting an error, so I started removing variables in the class. I found that removing all the structs named `vector2`, the compiler would be able to create an array of the class. I don't know why it doesn't work, or why a struct would affect it.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct vector2
{
    double x = 0, y = 0;
    vector2(double doubleX, double doubleY)
    {
        x = doubleX;
        y = doubleY;
    }
};

class Dog
{
    private:
        vector2 location;
        int age;

    public:
        void setLocation(vector2);
        vector2 getLocation();

        void setAge(int);
        int getAge();

};
void Dog::setLocation(vector2 newLocation)
{
    location = newLocation;
}
vector2 Dog::getLocation()
{
    return location;
}

void Dog::setAge(int newAge)
{
    age = newAge;
}
int Dog::getAge()
{
    return age;
}

int main() 
{
    Dog myDogs[1];
    myDogs[0].setAge(10);
    return 0;
}
```

BTW: I noticed some of the `vector2` code doesn't work, but I've tried this using a `std::vector`, and it works perfectly (with a constructor)

Comment: `vector2` doesn't have a default constructor: e.g. you can't write `vector2 v;`, only `vector2 v(1, 2);` Because of this, the compiler can't generate a default constructor for `Dog` either.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik How can I fix this? It won't let me do `vector2 location(0,0)` or `vector2 location(vector2(0,0));` in the `Dog` class

Comment: @Orfby See my answer below, those are two of your options (there are more)

Comment: @Igor: Please do not write answers in comments. This isn't a chat room.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Dog` has a `vector2` member variable, but `vector2` doesn't have a default constructor. And you don't have a `Dog` constructor that uses `vector2`'s parametrized constructor.

Either give `vector2` a default constructor

```
vector2::vector2() : x{0.0}, y{0.0} {}
```

Or have a constructor for `Dog` that uses the parametrized constructor of `vector2`

```
Dog::Dog(int _age) : age{_age}, location{0.0, 0.0} {}
```

Comment: The `vector2::vector2() : x{0.0}, y{0.0} {}` works perfectly in the program, thank you!